# Difference between === null and isNull in Spark DataDrame

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am bit confused with the difference when we are using

```
 df.filter(col("c1") === null) and df.filter(col("c1").isNull)
```

Same dataframe I am getting counts in 
=== null  but zero counts in isNull. Please help me to understand the difference. Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First and foremost don't use `null` in your Scala code unless you really have to for compatibility reasons.

Regarding your question it is plain SQL. `col("c1") === null` is interpreted as `c1 = NULL` and, because `NULL` marks undefined values, result is undefined for any value including `NULL` itself.

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT NULL = NULL").show
```

```
+-------------+
|(NULL = NULL)|
+-------------+
|         null|
+-------------+
```

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT NULL != NULL").show
```

```
+-------------------+
|(NOT (NULL = NULL))|
+-------------------+
|               null|
+-------------------+
```

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT TRUE != NULL").show
```

```
+------------------------------------+
|(NOT (true = CAST(NULL AS BOOLEAN)))|
+------------------------------------+
|                                null|
+------------------------------------+
```

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT TRUE = NULL").show
```

```
+------------------------------+
|(true = CAST(NULL AS BOOLEAN))|
+------------------------------+
|                          null|
+------------------------------+
```

The only valid methods to check for `NULL` are:

- `IS NULL`:

  ```scala
  spark.sql("SELECT NULL IS NULL").show
  ```

  ```
  +--------------+
  |(NULL IS NULL)|
  +--------------+
  |          true|
  +--------------+
  ```

  ```scala
  spark.sql("SELECT TRUE IS NULL").show
  ```

  ```
  +--------------+
  |(true IS NULL)|
  +--------------+
  |         false|
  +--------------+
  ```
- `IS NOT NULL`:

  ```scala
  spark.sql("SELECT NULL IS NOT NULL").show
  ```

  ```
  +------------------+
  |(NULL IS NOT NULL)|
  +------------------+
  |             false|
  +------------------+
  ```

  ```scala
  spark.sql("SELECT TRUE IS NOT NULL").show
  ```

  ```
  +------------------+
  |(true IS NOT NULL)|
  +------------------+
  |              true|
  +------------------+
  ```

implemented in `DataFrame` DSL as `Column.isNull` and `Column.isNotNull` respectively.

**Note**:

For `NULL`-safe comparisons use `IS DISTINCT` / `IS NOT DISTINCT`:

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM NULL").show
```

```
+---------------+
|(NULL <=> NULL)|
+---------------+
|           true|
+---------------+
```

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT NULL IS NOT DISTINCT FROM TRUE").show
```

```
+--------------------------------+
|(CAST(NULL AS BOOLEAN) <=> true)|
+--------------------------------+
|                           false|
+--------------------------------+
```

or  `not(_ <=> _)` / `<=>`

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT NULL AS col1, NULL AS col2").select($"col1" <=> $"col2").show
```

```
+---------------+
|(col1 <=> col2)|
+---------------+
|           true|
+---------------+
```

```scala
spark.sql("SELECT NULL AS col1, TRUE AS col2").select($"col1" <=> $"col2").show
```

```
+---------------+
|(col1 <=> col2)|
+---------------+
|          false|
+---------------+
```

in SQL and `DataFrame` DSL respectively.

**Related**:

[Including null values in an Apache Spark Join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41728762)

Answer (score 4):

Usually the best way to shed light onto unexpected results in Spark Dataframes is to look at the explain plan. Consider the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object Example extends App {

  val session = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  case class Record(c1: String, c2: String)
  val data = List(Record("a", "b"), Record(null, "c"))
  val rdd = session.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
  import session.implicits._

  val df: DataFrame = rdd.toDF
  val filtered = df.filter(col("c1") === null)
  println(filtered.count()) // <-- outputs 0, not expected

  val filtered2 = df.filter(col("c1").isNull)
  println(filtered2.count())
  println(filtered2) // <- outputs 1, as expected

  filtered.explain(true)
  filtered2.explain(true)
}
```

The first explain plan shows:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Filter (isnotnull(c1#2) && null)
+- Scan ExistingRDD[c1#2,c2#3]
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
'Filter isnull('c1)
+- LogicalRDD [c1#2, c2#3]
```

This filter clause looks nonsensical. The `&&` to `null` ensures this can never resolve to `true`.

The second explain plan looks like:

```
== Physical Plan ==
*Filter isnull(c1#2)
+- Scan ExistingRDD[c1#2,c2#3]
```

Here the filter is what expect and want.

Comment: Sorry I could not understand one thing.why I am getting some records when I use ===. How come it will be possible @mattinbits

Comment: Does your data actually have `null` in that column?

Comment: It is having some empty records(""),But the number of records returning is not matching with empty string when i use  === null. It will have both empty and non empty records.But I am getting null pointer exception when calling a udf that's  doesn't have a null check.