# count number of missing values using spark_apply

Tags: apache-spark, dplyr, apply, missing-data

I have the next data frame called **df**

```
ci ing de
21 20 100
22 19 0
23 NA 80
24 100 NA
25 NA 50
26 50 30
```

and I want to count the number of missings of each column using **spark**.

I know that in R a code like this would work

```
apply(df, 2, 
            FUN = function (x) 
            { sum(is.na(x)) }  )
```

I want to do the same but using **spark**

Spark has a function called **spark_apply**, but I can't figure it out how to make it work.

Comment: I would clarify what is meant by 'missings'. If you are inferring how to count NULL values in Spark, there is a good post here on working with NULL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41533290/difference-between-null-and-isnull-in-spark-datadrame

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Here "na" checking in df...

```
scala> nacount=df.na.count()
scala>nacount
2000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spark_apply(
  df,
  (function(e) sum(is.na(e)),
  names = c("your","column","names")
)
```

Try the above

Comment: returns 0 for class character and the sum of all NA's (over all cols) for class numeric --> that's not what's expected

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect but works for your purpose using spark_apply:

```
## count missing values by each column and group by category 
ci = c(21:26)
ing = c(20,19,NA,100,NA,50)
de = c(100,0,80,NA,50,30)
df = as.data.frame(list(ci=ci, ing=ing, de=de))
sdf = copy_to(sc, df)
count_na_col_i = function(i, sdf) {
  cns = colnames(sdf)
  cnt = spark_apply(sdf %>% select(cns[1], cns[i]) %>% mutate(x = cns[i]) %>% rename(y = cns[i]), #preparing data for spark_apply and renames as necessary
            f = function(tbl){
              require(dplyr)
              cn = as.character(collect(tbl %>% select("x") %>% distinct()))
              tbl %>% filter(is.na(y)) %>% count()
            }, columns = cns[i], group_by = cns[1])
  collect(cnt)
}
#i-th column only
i = 2
nna = count_na_col_i(2, sdf)
#all columns 
lapply(seq(2,length(colnames(sdf))), function(i, sdf) { count_na_col_i(i, sdf) }, sdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using @Charlie's `sdf` object:

```
sdf %>% spark_apply(function(e) apply(e, 2, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
```

will do the job.

The result is a df with one col containing the number of `NA`s of each column of `sdf` in one row. If needed, you can transpose it (`... %>% as.data.frame() %>% t()`) and add the colnames manually.

```
# Source:   table<sparklyr_tmp_3f7f4665748e> [?? x 1]
# Database: spark_connection
     ci
  <int>
1     0
2     2
3     1
```