# How to remove nulls with array_remove Spark SQL built-in function

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, null

Spark 2.4 introduced new useful Spark SQL functions involving arrays, but I was a little bit puzzled when I found out that the result of
`select array_remove(array(1, 2, 3, null, 3), null)` is `null` and not `[1, 2, 3, 3]`.

Is this the expected behavior? Is it possible to remove nulls using `array_remove`?

As a side note, for now the alternative I am using is a higher order function in Databricks:
`select filter(array(1, 2, 3, null, 3), x -> x is not null)`

Comment: The alternative is the way to go. `array_remove` depends on notion of equality, and [equality with `NULL` is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41533290/6910411).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html

array_remove(array, T): array
Remove all elements that equal to the given element from the given array.

Note: I only referred the documentation and they have taken the same data.
**null can never be equal to null.

Answer (score 17):

To answer your first question, "Is this the expected behavior?", yes. Because the official notebook (https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) points out "Remove all elements that equal to the given element from the given array." and
`NULL` corresponds to undefined values and the results will also be not defined.

So, I think `NULL` s are out of the purview of this function.

Better you found out a way to overcome this, you can also use `spark.sql("""SELECT array_except(array(1, 2, 3, 3, null, 3, 3,3, 4, 5), array(null))""").show()`, but the downside is that the result will be without duplicates.

Answer (score 11):

**Spark 3.4+**

```py
array_compact("col_name")
```

---

Full PySpark example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([([3, None, 3],)], ["c"])
df.show()
# +------------+
# |           c|
# +------------+
# |[3, null, 3]|
# +------------+

df = df.withColumn("c", F.array_compact("c"))

df.show()
# +------+
# |     c|
# +------+
# |[3, 3]|
# +------+
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this in Spark 2:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql._

/**
  * Array without nulls
  * For complex types, you are responsible for passing in a nullPlaceholder of the same type as elements in the array
  */
def non_null_array(columns: Seq[Column], nullPlaceholder: Any = "רכוב כל יום"): Column =
  array_remove(array(columns.map(c => coalesce(c, lit(nullPlaceholder))): _*), nullPlaceholder)
```

In Spark 3, there is new [array filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#filter(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) function and you can do:

```
df.select(filter(col("array_column"), x => x.isNotNull))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can use array_remove() or array_except() for your problem. However, though it's not a very good solution, but it may help.

```
@F.udf("array<string>")
def udf_remove_nulls(arr):
    return [i for i in arr if i is not None]

df = df.withColumn("col_wo_nulls", udf_remove_nulls(df["array_column"]))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you also want to get rid of duplicates, returning each distinct non-NULL value exactly once, you can use `array_except`:

```
f.array_except(f.col("array_column_with_nulls"), f.array(f.lit(None)))
```

or, equivalent, SQL like this:

```
array_except(your_array_with_NULLs, array())
```

Comment: I downvoted as this removes duplicates, and the asker wants to retain duplicates