# I need to append only those who has non null values in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am having the pyspark dataframe (df) having below sample table (table1):
    id, col1, col2, col3
    1, abc, null, def
    2, null, def, abc
    3, def, abc, null

I am trying to get new column (final) by appending the all the columns by ignoring null values.
I have tried pyspark code and used f.array(col1, col2, col3). Values are getting appended but it not ignoring null values. I have also tried UDF to append only non null columns but it is not working.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f    
df = spark.table('table1')
df = df.withColumn('final', f.array(col1,col2,col3))

Actual result:
id, col1, col2, col3, final
1, abc, null, def, [abc,,def]
2, null, def, abc, [,def, abc]
3, def, abc, null, [def,abc,,]

expected result:
id, col1, col2, col3, final
1, abc, null, def, [abc,def]
2, null, def, abc, [def, abc]
3, def, abc, null, [def,abc]


my col1, col2, col3 schema are as below:
where as col1 name is applications


applications: struct (nullable = false)
    applicationid: string (nullable = true)
    createdat: string (nullable = true)
    updatedat: string (nullable = true)
    source_name: string (nullable = true)
    status: string (nullable = true)
    creditbureautypeid: string (nullable = true)
    score: integer (nullable = true)
    applicationcreditreportid: string (nullable = true)
    firstname: string (nullable = false)
    lastname: string (nullable = false)
    dateofbirth: string (nullable = false)
    accounts: array (nullable = true)
        element: struct (containsNull = true)
        applicationcreditreportaccountid: string (nullable = true)
        currentbalance: integer (nullable = true)
        institutionid: string (nullable = true)
        accounttypeid: string (nullable = true)
        dayspastdue: integer (nullable = true)
        institution_name: string (nullable = true)
        account_type_name: string (nullable = true)
```

please let me know if question is not clear or any more info is required.
Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Actually, the version of pyspark probably won't make a difference: [How to remove nulls with array_remove Spark SQL Built-in Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159964/how-to-remove-nulls-with-array-remove-spark-sql-built-in-function/54176578#54176578)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Spark 2.4 you can use Higher Order Functions to do that (there is no UDF needed). In PySpark the query can look like this:

```
result = (
    df
    .withColumn("temp", f.array("col1", "col2", "col3"))
    .withColumn("final", f.expr("FILTER(temp, x -> x is not null)"))
    .drop("temp")
)
```

Comment: Great @David. Its works :) I have tried multiple solution but this works like a charm . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Using an UDF

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, array

def join_columns(row_list):
    return [cell_val for cell_val in row_list if cell_val is not None]

join_udf = udf(join_columns)

df = spark.table('table1')
df = df.withColumn('final', join_udf(array(col1,col2,col3))
```

Works for multiple columns not only just 3, just edit the columns inside the array.

Comment: thanks for your response ! its working however my columns schema are complex. I gave string column as an example.  When I am defining the function I have to give return type as well. I have mentioned my column schema.

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own `UDF` as follows:

```
def only_not_null(st,nd,rd):
   return [x for x in  locals().values() if x is not None]  # Take non empty columns
```

And then call:

```
df = spark.table('table1')
df = df.withColumn('final', f.udf(only_not_null)(col1,col2,col3))
```

Comment: why would you use `locals().values()`?

Comment: Also using `if x` is incorrect because that will filter out any Falsey values like `0` or `''`