# Intervals array from dates array

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column with an array of dates, I would like to know the most efficient way to extract a new column with an array of intervals (in days) between the dates.

| ID | DATES |
| --- | --- |
| X | `[01-01-2001, 03-01-2001, 10-01-2001, 25-01-2001]` |
| Y | ... |
| Z | ... |

Should become:

| ID | DATES | INTERVALS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | `[01-01-2001, 03-01-2001, 10-01-2001, 25-01-2001]` | `[2, 7, 15]` |
| Y | ... |  |
| Z | ... |  |

I have UDF parsing the array and substracting the dates one by one, but I'm sure there is a most efficient way to do it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a very large data frame and/or the sizes of your date arrays vary greatly, using the Spark SQL functions to explode, calculate, and re-collect your values *may* be more performant than a UDF.

Setup:

```py
import datetime

df = spark.createDataFrame([
  {
    "ID": "X", 
    "DATES": [
      datetime.date(2001, 1, 1), 
      datetime.date(2001, 1, 3), 
      datetime.date(2001, 1, 10), 
      datetime.date(2001, 1, 25)
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "Y", 
    "DATES": [
      datetime.date(2003, 1, 1), 
      datetime.date(2006, 3, 2), 
      datetime.date(2007, 5, 1), 
      datetime.date(2009, 8, 2)
    ]
  }
])
```

The most complex part of this approach is ensuring your dates and resulting remain in order throughout, which is accomplished below with the window function:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

w = Window.partitionBy("ID").orderBy("DATE")

df_intervals = df \
  .select("ID", F.explode("DATES").alias("DATE")) \
  .withColumn("DATES", F.collect_list("DATE").over(w)) \
  .withColumn("INTERVALS", F.collect_list(F.datediff("DATE", F.lag("DATE").over(w))).over(w)) \
  .groupBy("ID") \
  .agg(F.max("DATES").alias("DATES"), F.max("INTERVALS").alias("INTERVALS"))
```

Comment: Thank you. Took me some time to understand the steps but it is perfect for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use the [transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function as shown below:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df = spark.createDataFrame([
[["01-01-2001", "03-01-2001", "10-01-2001", "25-01-2001"]]
], ["dates"]) 

df.withColumn("dates", expr("transform(dates, x -> to_date(x,'dd-MM-yyyy'))"))\
  .withColumn("diff", expr("array_remove(transform(dates, (x, i) -> if(i > 0, datediff(dates[i] , dates[i-1]), -1)), -1)"))\
  .show(100, False)

# +------------------------------------------------+----------+
# |dates                                           |diff      |
# +------------------------------------------------+----------+
# |[01-01-2001, 03-01-2001, 10-01-2001, 25-01-2001]|[2, 7, 15]|
# +------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

With the first transformation we convert string items to date. Then we iterate through each item computing the expression `if(i > 0, datediff(dates[i], dates[i-1]), -1)`.

*Explanation*

- `When index(i) > 0` get the difference between current date and the previous one using `datediff` which returns the difference in days.
- `Otherwise` return -1. Note that we will need always to remove this. We use -1 instead of `null` because is easier to remove it from an array (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54159964/how-to-remove-nulls-with-array-remove-spark-sql-built-in-function) for more info)
- Eventually with `array_remove` delete redundant -1 from the array